# MPMoviePlayerController changing video speed

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is there a way to play video at double speed using MPMoviePlayerController?

```
myMPMoviePlayerController.currentPlaybackRate = 2.f
```

doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 12):

Play the movie first, then set the playback rate.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the setCurrentPlaybackRate method, like this:

```
[myMPMoviePlayerController setCurrentPlaybackRate:2.f];
```

Answer (score 0):

Even it's bit old question now but I would like to share if someone having same problem.

Here is the code sample I am using and **its working with me**

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        MPMoviePlayerViewController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                 initWithContentURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];
        [theMovie.moviePlayer play];
        theMovie.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackRate = 2.00f;//here we can set speed
        theMovie.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;

        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];
    }
    }];
}
```

Hope this will help someone.